Error encountered while implementing Google sign-in in Flutter app: 'This operation is not allowed
I try to use google signin in my app. The first time I used it, everything worked fine, I was able to sign in. But the next times I just get this text in console:
W/System  ( 4510): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
I/flutter ( 4510): [firebase_auth/operation-not-allowed] This operation is not allowed. This may be because the given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section. [ The identity provider configuration is not found.

I am sure that my sign-in provider is enabled in firebase.
Here is my code.
void _signInWithGoogle(BuildContext context) async {
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  try {
    final currentUser = _firebaseAuth.currentUser;

    // Check if the user is already signed in
    if (currentUser != null) {
      // If user is already signed in, navigate directly to home page
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
      );
      return;
    }

    // Sign in with Google
    final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount = await _googleSignIn.signIn();

    if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
        accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
      );

      await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);

      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
      );
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}



Try clearing the app data or cache (if it's a mobile app) and attempt to sign in again.

The provided code seems correct, but you can remove the null check for X-Firebase-Locale header as it's not directly related to the sign-in issue.

Go to your Firebase console and navigate to Authentication --> Sign-in method. Ensure the toggle for Google is switched on.

After any async await operation check if the context is still alive by adding
if(mounted) {//do navigation}


